# Upgraded to IOS5 - App Won't Build

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've upgraded my IOS4.3 app to IOS5 and am getting compile errors. From what I can tell, the syntax looks fine, but the compiler is complaining of "Unexpected @" when I synthesize properties, but only in some classes.

I also have an "Undeclared identifier" in one ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method.

I've performed a clean build and I'm guessing that there's a default setting which has been changed somewhere, but from scouring around this doesn't seem to be a common issue. Is there a list of common breaking changes anywhere?

**EDIT:**
This screenshot is one of my ViewControllers, which is derived from UITableViewController
[image: Example UITableViewController]

Comment: can you post the code where you get the errors?

Comment: The error is probably higher up than the screen shot. What is the first error you get?  You might just have a stray character or something trivial

Comment: Can you post WHOLE error log?

Comment: I can't post the whole log as it contains details of an unreleased app, but I do find it interesting that the declaration for MKAnnotation can't be found, even though the 5.0 MapKit framework is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from a .NET/PHP background, I have very little experience with compilers. The problem was that Apple seem to have changes the default compiler for IOS5 from GCC to LLVM, hence the difference in syntax. It would be nice to be able to use the newer compiler, but GCC's the only one which gets anywhere near close.

Answer (score 4):

There is a missing `@` in the line `self.title = NSLocalizedString(...)`. The second parameter doesn't have the leading @.